# How could I parse this date value transferred from model to javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parsing, date

```
 var time =<%:Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AvailableDates))%>;
 var parsed = time[0];
 alert( parsed );
```

The pop up shows: "/Date(1174021200000)/". It is not a instance of date. I tried .toString("mm/dd/yy"), Date.parse(parsed), new Date(parsed). Unfortunately, none of these works. I dont wanna let my controller return a formatted value. Is there a way I can parse it on client side? thank you. By the way AvailableDates is a list of datetime in c#.

Comment: Try this, var re = /-?\d+/;  var m = re.exec(parsed);  var d = new Date(parseInt(m[0]));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse it like this:

```
var date = new Date(<% Model.AvailableDates %>);
```

Comment: then you have to iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

Try use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
 var time =<%:Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AvailableDates))%>;
 var parsed =  moment(time);
  alert( parsed );
```

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LSc5b/) in jsfiddle